# MPI Non-blocking Irecv didn't receive data?

Tags: nonblocking, openmpi

I use MPI non-blocking communication(MPI_Irecv, MP_Isend) to monitor the slaves' idle states, the code is like bellow.

rank 0:

```c
int dest = -1;
while( dest <= 0){
   int i;
   for(i=1;i<=slaves_num;i++){
      printf("slave %d, now is %d \n",i,idle_node[i]);
      if (idle_node[i]== 1) {
         idle_node[i] = 0;
         dest = i;
         break;
      }
   }
   if(dest <= 0){
      MPI_Irecv(&idle_node[1],1,MPI_INT,1,MSG_IDLE,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
      MPI_Irecv(&idle_node[2],1,MPI_INT,2,MSG_IDLE,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
      MPI_Irecv(&idle_node[3],1,MPI_INT,3,MSG_IDLE,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
      // MPI_Wait(&request,&status);
   }
   usleep(100000);
}

idle_node[dest] = 0;//indicates this slave is busy now
```

rank 1,2,3:

```c
while(1)
{
   ...//do something
   MPI_Isend(&idle,1,MPI_INT,0,MSG_IDLE,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request);
   MPI_Wait(&request,&status);
}
```

it works, but I want it to be faster, so I delete the line:

```c
usleep(100000);
```

then rank 0 goes into a dead while like this:

```
slave 1, now is 0
slave 2, now is 0
slave 3, now is 0 
slave 1, now is 0
slave 2, now is 0
slave 3, now is 0 
...
```

So does it indicate that when I use the `MPI_Irecv`, it just tells MPI I want to receive a message here（haven't received message), and MPI needs other time to receive the real data? or some reasons else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of non-blocking operations has been discussed over and over again here. From the MPI specification (section *Nonblocking Communication*):

> Similarly, a nonblocking **receive start call** initiates the receive operation, but does not complete it. The call can return before a message is stored into the receive buffer. A separate **receive complete** call is needed to complete the receive operation and verify that the data has been received into the receive buffer. *With suitable hardware, the transfer of data into the receiver memory may proceed concurrently with computations done after the receive was initiated and before it completed.*

(the **bold text** is copied verbatim from the standard; the emphasis in *italic* is mine)

The key sentence is the last one. The standard does not give any guarantee that a non-blocking receive operation will ever complete (or even start) unless `MPI_WAIT[ALL|SOME|ANY]` or `MPI_TEST[ALL|SOME|ANY]` was called (with `MPI_TEST*` setting a value of true for the completion flag).

By default Open MPI comes as a single-threaded library and without special hardware acceleration the only way to progress non-blocking operations is to either call periodically into some non-blocking calls (with the primary example of `MPI_TEST*`) or call into a blocking one (with the primary example being `MPI_WAIT*`).

Also your code leads to a nasty leak that will sooner or later result in resource exhaustion: you are calling `MPI_Irecv` multiple times with the same `request` variable, effectively overwriting its value and losing the reference to the previously started requests. Requests that are not waited upon are never freed and therefore remain in memory.

There is absolutely no need to use non-blocking operations in your case. If I understand the logic correctly, you can achieve what you want with code as simple as:

```c
MPI_Recv(&dummy, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MSG_IDLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
idle_node[status.MPI_SOURCE] = 0;
```

If you'd like to process more than one worker processes at the same time, it is a bit more involving:

```c
MPI_Request reqs[slaves_num];
int indices[slaves_num], num_completed;

for (i = 0; i < slaves_num; i++)
   reqs[i] = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;

while (1)
{
   // Repost all completed (or never started) receives
   for (i = 1; i <= slaves_num; i++)
      if (reqs[i-1] == MPI_REQUEST_NULL)
         MPI_Irecv(&idle_node[i], 1, MPI_INT, i, MSG_IDLE,
                   MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i-1]);

   MPI_Waitsome(slaves_num, reqs, &num_completed, indices, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);

   // Examine num_completed and indices and feed the workers with data
   ...
}
```

After the call to `MPI_Waitsome` there will be one or more completed requests. The exact number will be in `num_completed` and the indices of the completed requests will be filled in the first `num_completed` elements of `indices[]`. The completed requests will be freed and the corresponding elements of `reqs[]` will be set to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`.

Also, there appears to be a common misconception about using non-blocking operations. A non-blocking send can be matched by a blocking receive and also a blocking send can be equally matched by a non-blocking receive. That makes such constructs nonsensical:

```c
// Receiver
MPI_Irecv(..., &request);
... do something ...
MPI_Wait(&request, &status);

// Sender
MPI_Isend(..., &request);
MPI_Wait(&request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

`MPI_Isend` immediately followed by `MPI_Wait` is **equivalent** to `MPI_Send` and the following code is perfectly valid (and easier to understand):

```c
// Receiver
MPI_Irecv(..., &request);
... do something ...
MPI_Wait(&request, &status);

// Sender
MPI_Send(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you're absolutely right. This helps a lot for the new fishers like me. according to your first proposal that using MPI_Recv() to receive messages from work processes, does it mean that the mount of recv methods and the mount fo send methods hasn't to be equal?

Comment: Blocking receives have to be matched by the same number of sends, otherwise if the number of sends is lower, the receive will hang indefinitely.

Comment: That's right. and about your answer I think the first parameter of: `MPI_Waitsome(slaves_num-1, reqs, &num_completed, indices, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);` should be **slaves_num** (doesn't need to minus 1). Not a big problem, it works, :).

Comment: Ooops, that's what happens when one tries to write two different code versions at the same time.

Comment: If you used MPI_Waitall, then you wouldn't need the infinite loop right?

Comment: That's correct. If you use `MPI_Waitall`, it won't return until all provided requests have been completed.